# Use border image only for bottom border? Our CSS seems to replicate the image across the whole div instead

Tags: html, css

We would like to use an image only for the bottom of a DIV. However, our CSS somehow replicates the image across the body of the DIV instead of placing it at the bottom.

What are we doing wrong?

We only need to support mobile Safari.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ZwnF8/

Code:

```
<div></div>​

div { background:gray; 
      width:100px;
      height:100px;
      margin-left:20px;
      -webkit-border-image:url(http://www.panabee.com/images/dumpling/footer_list.png) 0 0 8 0 round
     }​
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Method 1:** set `0` width to all (except `border-bottom`):

```
border-image:url("http://lorempixel.com/g/400/100/?example.jpg");
border-top:0;
border-left:0;
border-right:0;
// btw, you can use "one-line" command>   border-width: 0 0 3px 0;
```

**Method 2:** with style.css, create  **`::AFTER`** phseudo-element:

```
.yourDiv::after { 
    content:"";
    height:20px; 
    width:100%; /* or i.e: 500px */
    background:url("http://lorempixel.com/g/400/100/?example.jpg");
}
```

Comment: Method 2 is a fun solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Try with -webkit-border-bottom-image . Don't forget to include non-webkit browsers. Here is an useful link : http://css-tricks.com/understanding-border-image/

Comment: From your link: The default behavior is supposed to be to discard the center section of the image, and use the 'fill' keyword on the border-image-slice property to preserve it:
    The ‘fill’ keyword, if present, causes the middle part of the border-image to be preserved. (By default it is discarded, i.e., treated as empty.)
But the current browser behavior is to preserve the middle, and there is no way to turn it off. Thus, if you don't want your element's content area to have a background, the center section of your image must be empty.

Comment: @gabitzish, -webkit-border-bottom-image didn't work for us ... did it for you?

Answer (score 4):

You've defined it to repeat as "round":
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-image-repeat.asp

Here's how you can define each individual attribute:

```css
div { background:gray; 
      width:100px;
      height:100px;
      margin-left:20px;
      -webkit-border-image:url(http://www.panabee.com/images/dumpling/footer_list.png);
      -webkit-border-image-width: 0 0 8px 0;
      -webkit-border-image-repeat: stretch;
      border-image: url(http://www.panabee.com/images/dumpling/footer_list.png);
      border-image-width: 0 0 8px 0;
      border-image-repeat: stretch;
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

this is used to put the border image in the bottom of the div

```
     <html>
        <head>
           <style>
           .target{
        height:100px;
        width:100px;
        border-image: url(Images/line.png) 0 0 5 0;
        border-top: 0px;
        border-left: 0px;
        border-right: 0px;
        border-bottom:8px;
        } 
       </style>
       </head>
       <body>
         <div class="target">

         </div>
         </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about safari mobile but I killed the border part of your css on the fiddle and put this below your div:

```
<div></div><img src="http://www.panabee.com/images/dumpling/footer_list.png" style="height:20px;width:100px;margin-left:20px;"/>
```

And it did what it seems like you want it to. Does safari mobile not support something like this?

Answer (score 1):

look at this [jsfiddle.net/ocewa9sm/](https://jsfiddle.net/ocewa9sm/)

```
#borderimg {
 background: #dfdfdf;
 padding: 15px;
 position: relative;}

#borderimg:after {  
 content: "";
 border-bottom: 16px solid transparent;
 width: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 bottom: -16px;

 -webkit-border-image: url(http://www.panabee.com/images/dumpling/footer_list.png); 
 -o-border-image: url(http://www.panabee.com/images/dumpling/footer_list.png);
 border-image: url(http://www.panabee.com/images/dumpling/footer_list.png) ;

 border-image-slice: 8;
 border-image-width: 8px;
 border-image-outset: 0;
 border-image-repeat: stretch;
}
```

Comment: There is one more way.. ":after" element to put an "absolute bottom background-image" .. But it does not give a healthy result.. and look at these links https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/border-image/ https://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/border-image-slice