# Use as image for bottom border: possible to repeat image in the "after" pseudo element and control background size?

Tags: html, css

We are trying unsuccessfully to use a single image as a bottom border. See our attempt here: [Use border image only for bottom border? Our CSS seems to replicate the image across the whole div instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10164393/use-border-image-only-for-bottom-border-our-css-seems-to-replicate-the-image-ac)

Now we're attempting to use the "after" pseudo element as a border bottom image.

The problem is we cannot define the size of the image in the content property nor make it repeat across the width of the pseudo element. Is this possible?

Comment: We're putting an image into the content property, but we cannot set the height and width of the image nor make it repeat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.some-div:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 100px; /* example */
    height: 2px;
    background: url('../images/path-to-your-image.png') repeat-x;
}
```

You just have to add some positioning based on your code (float, absolute, anything).