# How to add a border-bottom-image with css

Tags: html, image, css

I created the following image to be rendered under all h1 title tags in my website. Trouble is, every tutorial I find online discusses border image property as a all around border.

All I want to achieve is to get this one small image underneath the title, once. No repeat. centered. According to this http://www.css3.info/preview/border-image/ there is a property called border-bottom-image. But I can't seem to get it to display properly.

Google chrome developer tools tells me that this is an unknown property name. If I can't achieve this with the following css3, how can I achieve it?

```
.entry-title{
border-bottom-image: url(images/title-borderbottom.jpg);
}
```

[image]

Comment: You could try setting it as the border image, like the tutorials you referenced show how, then just having the bottom border thickness being greater than zero.

Comment: Try `-webkit-border-bottom-image` or use pseudo element `:after`

Comment: I don't think `border-image` is what you want, primarily because the `center no-repeat` directive you want is not supported (the way you want it; `stretch` is closest, but it's not *really* the same). This is as close as I got: http://jsfiddle.net/mh66rvbo/ You could use [`background-image`](http://jsfiddle.net/mh66rvbo/1/) instead, with a bottom padding, if that doesn't disrupt other background styles on the elements. See this very explanatory entry from CSS Tricks: https://css-tricks.com/understanding-border-image/

Comment: Here is another StackOverflow thread that asks this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10164393/use-border-image-only-for-bottom-border-our-css-seems-to-replicate-the-image-ac

Comment: Have you tried `border-bottom-style: solid;`?

Comment: Could you use a div with a background image? http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp

Comment: Another version of `background-image` using `:after`: http://jsfiddle.net/mh66rvbo/2/

Comment: Normally it's not easy to get border-image working the way you want, and [it's not well supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=border-image), why not using background image? quick demo - http://jsfiddle.net/pxra15wL/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here are two options that allow you to do what you want without resorting to `border-image`, which is not really built for what you want to do.

## background-image + :after

This uses a pseudo-element (`:after`) to "insert" a block with your given image as the `background-image`. I think this is probably better than the next option, since it's least disruptive to the element's styling.

```
.entry-title:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 70px;
    background-image: url(http://placehold.it/350x65);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center bottom;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mh66rvbo/2/

## background-image + padding

This uses `padding-bottom` to make space for the image, then sticks the image along the bottom of the element, positioning in the center.

```
.entry-title {
    padding-bottom: 70px;
    background-image: url(http://placehold.it/350x65);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center bottom;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mh66rvbo/1/

Comment: Thank you so much Jared!! That fixed my problem. I was playing around with the border image thing so much, getting it to "almost" work, but never really looking right. This solved it. You are a lifesaver :)

Answer (score 1):

work for me ....

```
.entry-title{
    border-bottom: 20px solid #000;
    border-image:url('bottom.jpeg');
    border-image-repeat: round;
    border-image-slice: 300;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px auto;
    width:70%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  By such an old question however it very much helps if you provide some explanation as to how your solution differs from the old ones, and why it is preferable.

Answer (score 0):

From the link you provided (http://www.css3.info/preview/border-image/)

> border-image currently works in Safari and Firefox 3.1 (Alpha).

Per my understanding, "border-bottom-image" still doesn't work in the latest version of Google Chrome (natively). But "border-image" does. And you can define width for each individual portion using the (top right bottom left) protocol:

```css
.entry-title{
border-image: url(images/title-borderbottom.jpg);
border-image-width: 0 0 10px 0;
border-image-repeat: stretch;
}
```

Details: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-image.asp

Comment: `border-image-repeat: none` is not [a valid value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image-repeat).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @JaredFarrish - "stretch" should work in this case.

Comment: The downside, of course, is that it will deform the image if it's not setup to be stretched, which may or may not be desirable.

Comment: True. Then, like you pointed-out, it shouldn't be rendered a "border" as borders inherently stretch around the object.

Comment: Yes, I played with stretch and it was always funky looking. Never pixel perfect.